# order by nested class property

Tags: c#, linq

I have following class structure

```
public class PriceClass
    {  
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        public int product_id { get; set; }

    }

    public class NameClass
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

    }

    public class ProductDetails
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string product_type { get; set; }
         public List<NameClass> nameCl{ get; set; }
        public List<PriceClass> priceCl{ get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductLists
    {
        public List<ProductDetails> ProductDet{ get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to sort the ProductLists with price i.e. in priceClass class

I tried with some solution but that does not seems working

```
prdList = (ProductLists )prdList.ProductDet.OrderBy(r => r.priceCl.OrderBy(x => x.price).ToList());
```

But it seems i am no where around its solution
Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: I assume `priceClass` should rather be called `Product`. Doesn't it?

Comment: Btw Classes begin with capital letter... and your are switching between small and capital beginning of the class. maybe change this first for better code readability

Comment: I have updated the code, there was some issue with structure, I hope this fine now

Comment: Not clear what should happen: Sort on highest price in priceCl? Lowest? average? We need a **single** value as a sort criterium.

Comment: Can you please clarify how list of {1,5, 6} should be compared to  {9, 2}?

Answer (score 2):

It is just simpler:

```
sorted_ProductDet_List = prdList.ProductDet
     .OrderBy(prDet => prDet.sortPrice)
     .ToList());
```

Then you'll have to add a Property `sortPrice` to priceDetail which returns the relevant price used as sort criterium.

The lambda inside `OrderBy` works on a single element of the original List (List) and specifies the variable/property/etc (probably from any nested class or method) the sorting is based on.

Comment: @Md. Parvez Alam: what? I think the solution is doing pretty fine.

Comment: What does `priceCl.price` mean? (`priceCl` seem to be list...)

Comment: Added question in comment to your question and edited my answer

Comment: Yes, but one product has a list of prices. What to do with these many prices? (see Alexei's comment above)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom IComparer to compare the product details.

```
public class ProductDetailsComparer : IComparer<ProductDetails>
{
    private bool _compareMinPrice;

    public ProductDetailsComparer(bool compareMinPrice)
    {
        _compareMinPrice = compareMinPrice;
    }

    public int Compare(ProductDetails x, ProductDetails y)
    {
        var left = _compareMinPrice ? x.priceCl.Min(p => p.price) : x.priceCl.Max(p => p.price);
        var right = _compareMinPrice ? y.priceCl.Min(p => p.price) : y.priceCl.Max(p => p.price);

        return left.CompareTo(right);
    }
}
```

You can use the custom comparer in OrderBy as shown below.

```
// Sort by minimum price
        var ascending = productLists.ProductDet.OrderBy(x => x, new ProductDetailsComparer(true)).ToList();
        // Sort by maximum price
        var descending = productLists.ProductDet.OrderBy(x => x, new ProductDetailsComparer(false)).ToList();
```

The above is just a sample. You can write a custom comparer suiting your requirements.